# Qual é a finalidade do arquivo "persistence.xml"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou estudando a respeito do *Hibernate*, e no caminho me surgiu varias duvidas, umas das minhas duvidas, e que é importante para o meu aprendizado, é a respeito da finalidade do arquivo **`persistence.xml`** que é minha unidade de persistência, já li a respeito, porem, não consigo compreender sua finalidade.

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade deste arquivo em relação a minha aplicação e qual é a relevância que ele tem no meu projeto?

Comment: Não entendi o negativo, eu achei boa a pergunta. Até porque não sei se o `persistence.xml` tem a ver com o Hibernate, esse arquivo não é geral do JPA? O Hibernate não usa o `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: Eu não sei, eu sei que o Hibernate precisa dele, sei muito pouco a respeito deste arquivo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `persistence.xml` é um arquivo de configuração usado pelo JPA, o Hibernate é uma das muitas implementações do JPA. O conteúdo desse arquivo tem informações como  a *url de conexão*, *usuário*, *senha*. Além de conter mapeamento das classes que se tornaram as tabelas, e este mapeamento é feito através das anotações.

Exemplo de um arquivo `persistence.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="Hello" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Hello"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Em `<persistence-unit name=”Hello” transaction-type=”RESOURCE_LOCAL”>` duas configurações importantes são definidas aqui.

Em `unit name` define para a aplicação a configuração que será utilizada. No mesmo arquivo podemos ter vários tipos diferentes, como `transaction-type` que define como será nosso tipo de transação, em nosso caso `local`. Caso fosse uma aplicação web não iríamos precisar controlar a transação, o containner (JBoss, GlassFish,) faria esse trabalho.

Em `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` indica qual será o provider de nossa aplicação. Em nosso caso, o Hibernate.

A opção `hibernate.show_sql` habilita a exibição do SQL gerado no console.

Em `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver` define qual será o agente de conexão com o banco de dados que estaremos utilizando, vamos utilizar o MySQL, `javax.persistence.jdbc.url` a URL de nosso banco de dados juntamente com o schema de nosso banco de dados.

Em `javax.persistence.jdbc.user` e `javax.persistence.jdbc.password` usuário e senha do banco de dados. Esses atributos foram definidos na instalação do MySQL. Utilizei os valores `root` e `root`.

Em `hibernate.dialect` o dialeto que o Hibernate irá utilizar. Vamos discutir mais sobre essa opção em posts futuros, por exemplo, como gerar script do banco de dados de modo automático.

Esta opção `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` definida como ativada, o Hibernate atualizará suas tabelas quando necessário. Por exemplo, se a tabela não existir ela irá criar (`CREATE TABLE`), se você adicionou uma coluna nova (`ALTER TABLE`).

Referencias:
http://www.inf.ufg.br/~fabrizzio/as/aulas/aula7.pdf
http://uaihebert.com/tutorial-hibernate-3-com-jpa-2/

Comment: A sim, ele é parte da implementação do JPA.

Comment: Sim, è nesse arquivo que estão as configurações do JPA

Answer (score 1):

O persistence.xml é um arquivo para configuração do JPA,o hibernate é uma das implementações, tanto para hibernate ou outra implementação de JPA se faz necessário o uso desse arquivo, não sei era essa sua duvida, mas tá ai;
Esse traz detalhes dessas configurações é utilizado o eclipseLink como implementação, mas acredito que pode ajudar
http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-livro-primeiros-passos-e-conceitos-detalhados/4/